# Is it possible to change the default text for a Charge plugin checkout button

Tags: plugin-charge

I'm trying to set up a simple subscription based site using the Awesome Charge plugin and am wondering if I can change the button text using Stripe Checkout.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation around Checkout Options on the Squarebit site that indicates I can pass a value, through the options list, that changes the text 'Pay with card' to something else.

I understand I could customise the whole process using the Strip.js method but was hoping to just use the out of the box version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer of [Charge](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge) here.

Yes - you absolutely can control the label generated for the checkout button.

When setting the details for the checkout option, you just need to pass a sub-array called `checkout`, along with the extra parameters that get passed straight down the modal js.

Specifically you'd want do some thing like this :

```
{% set options = {
    planAmount : 99.99,
    description : 'This is an optional description for the modal',
    checkout : {
        name: 'Company Name ltd.',
        image: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/stripe-uploads/hSYxIZGM3U0DbmPKsJszRHm3OU3D4CtHmerchant-icon-641868-add-on-icon.png',
        label: 'Pay with Stripe Checkout'
    }
 } %}

 {{ craft.charge.setCheckoutOptions(options) }}
```

In that above example you can see we're passing values for `name`, `image` and `label` to the Checkout modal.

That'll return a button that looks something like this :

[image: Example Stripe Checkout button with custom label]

The full details of all the configuration options you can pass through to the checkout modal are detailed in the [Stripe Checkout documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple-options). Just pass the values you want within that `checkout` array in the twig.

NB. We're working on updating the docs on this usage right now, and they'll be up shortly too [here](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge/usage/reference/checkout-options)